# How to confirm that all checkbox are checked before doing something?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

My goal is If all checkbox are check the person can go further if not it will go to an excuse page.

I found this in jQuery:

```
$("input[type='checkbox'].itemCheck").change(function(){
    var a = $("input[type='checkbox'].itemCheck");
    if(a.length == a.filter(":checked").length){
        console.log("Je vais sur la formulaire");

    }
});
```

I tried it and it works but I need it in vanilla js so I tried to convert it but I just can't find out how to accomplish this.

I tried other logic to make it work but I can't figure how.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="verif" class="checkbox itemCheck">

<input type="checkbox"  name="age" class="checkbox itemCheck">

<input type="checkbox"  name="employed" class="checkbox itemCheck">
```

Comment: I assume the `s` is not really in your code.

Comment: So what is your problem? You seem to have the code hooked up with the change event and getting the checked count. So you do not know how to select elements in plain JavaScript? querySelectorAll ?

Comment: Use querySelectorAll along with forEach and attach an event listener. In the loop, compare length of checked with length of checkables (new word alert, haha)

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for the s haha

And yes i don't really know to do it plain js

Comment: @korwalskiy ok i will try using querySelectorAll & forEach thank

Comment: You could use something like: document.querySelectorAll(
    'input[type="checkbox"]:checked'
  ).length; to get the length of checked checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vanilla JavaScript version of that jQuery code would be: (Added comments so you can understand what is happening)

```
// gets all the inputs on the page with type = "checkbox"
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
// loops through each checkbox
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  // add an change event listener to each checkbox
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    // gets the checkboxes that are ticked (or "checked")
    var checkboxes_ticked = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    // check if the length of ticked checkboxes matches with the total checkboxes on the page
    if (checkboxes_ticked.length === checkboxes.length) {
      // all checkboxes where ticked! display your message
      console.log("Je vais sur la formulaire");
    }
  });
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, is was the loop that i think i had difficulties and the check the total.

And thank you very much for the comments! it help a lot to understand!